# HTML5 canvas circle lag on display

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, owl-carousel

I'm trying to set some canvas circle percentage values over a basic owl caroussel, the problem that i'm facing is a lag when you scroll, there are some values whom don't display until they reach the first place on the caroussel, anyone knows how to fix this problem ?

There is an image down bellow, to explain what i'm talking about, i've also added the snippet code, so you can check it out.

Thanks everyone.

[image]

```js
/* OWL CAROUSSEL JS*/

$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".owl-carousel").owlCarousel({
    loop: true,
    margin: 20,
    nav: true,
    dots: true,
    responsive: {
      0: {
        items: 1
      },
      600: {
        items: 3
      },
      1000: {
        items: 5
      }
    }
  });
});

/* CANVAS JS */
function progressSim(id, percent) {
  var ctx = document.getElementById(id).getContext('2d'),
    cw = ctx.canvas.width,
    ch = ctx.canvas.height,
    al = 0,
    sim = setInterval(progress, 25);

  function progress() {
    var start = 4.72,
      diff = ((al / 100) * Math.PI * 2 * 10).toFixed(2);

    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, cw, ch);
    ctx.lineWidth = 7;
    ctx.fillStyle = '#000';
    ctx.strokeStyle = "#000";
    ctx.textAlign = 'center';
    ctx.font = "30px Arial";
    ctx.fillText(al + '%', cw * .5, ch * .5 + 2, cw);
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(80, 80, 70, start, diff / 10 + start, false);
    ctx.stroke();
    if (al >= percent) {
      clearTimeout(sim);
      // Add scripting here that will run when progress completes
    }
    al++;
  };
}

progressSim('my_canvas1', 65);
progressSim('my_canvas2', 80);
progressSim('my_canvas3', 90);
progressSim('my_canvas4', 15);
progressSim('my_canvas5', 35);
progressSim('my_canvas6', 68);
progressSim('my_canvas7', 89);
progressSim('my_canvas8', 14);
```

```css
.item {
  width: 200px;
  height: 230px;
  background-color: orange;
  padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
}

#container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 550px;
  background-color: #d82c2e;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>

<head>
  <!--BS CSS-->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">

  <!--BS JS-->
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


  <!--OWL CSS-->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.3.4/assets/owl.carousel.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.3.4/assets/owl.theme.default.min.css">

</head>

<body>
  <div id="=container">
    <div class="owl-carousel owl-theme">
      <div class="item">
        <h4>Value 1 </h4><canvas id="my_canvas1" width="170" height="170"></canvas></div>
      <div class="item">
        <h4>Value 2 </h4><canvas id="my_canvas2" width="170" height="170"></canvas></div>
      <div class="item">
        <h4>Value 3 </h4><canvas id="my_canvas3" width="170" height="170"></canvas></div>
      <div class="item">
        <h4>Value 4 </h4><canvas id="my_canvas4" width="170" height="170"></canvas></div>
      <div class="item">
        <h4>Value 5 </h4><canvas id="my_canvas5" width="170" height="170"></canvas></div>
      <div class="item">
        <h4>Value 6 </h4><canvas id="my_canvas6" width="170" height="170"></canvas></div>
      <div class="item">
        <h4>Value 7 </h4><canvas id="my_canvas7" width="170" height="170"></canvas></div>
      <div class="item">
        <h4>Value 8 </h4><canvas id="my_canvas8" width="170" height="170"></canvas></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!--OWL JS-->
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.3.4/owl.carousel.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please find **working example of owl carousel with canvas items** bellow steps:

1. Owl carousel **creates clones of previous/next items** to allow group loop (e.g. than you clicked on navigation balls). As result you see clone of item, but during simple cloning of canvas element, the image will not be cloned.
2. So you need to initialize canvas (call `progressSim()`) for each cloned element, but such as plugin doesn't allow you to get only cloned elements, you can filter them by class `cloned` or use flag for already initialized items (I prefered second way).
3. You set an *"id"* attribute for each item of carousel, which is bad idea, because you can get **duplicate of same `id`** in DOM (do to cloning).
4. It's good to **use same class for all items** and call `progressSim()` only once, not for all items separately, because count of items can be dynamic.

> Fiddle of  [example of owl carousel with canvas](https://codepen.io/saribekyantaron/pen/MBZbgj)
>   Take a look **some comments in JS code** section

[Github issue connected with this question.](https://github.com/OwlCarousel2/OwlCarousel2/issues/2413)

Answer (score 1):

when set to loop, the items in owl carousel are cloned, you will end up with more than one `id="my_canvas1"` which can create conflict, but more importantly the cloned element won't even exist in the DOM whe you are calling your functions progressSim(id, percent)

I can take a closer look if you have a codepen or jsfiddle example I can edit.

Comment: I tried to put images instead, it works well, i can see all items when i scroll, but not the canvas circles, so the function progressSim() has a conflict problem between the items, right ? this is the codepen link: https://codepen.io/m4t/pen/zLMZrB